# Spring Boot integration tests HeadlessException with config class containing swing content

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know that Spring Boot has issues loading the context when there is a swing component pop-up. I've read [here](https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/solved-caused-by-java-awt-headlessexception-when-trying-to-create-a-swingawt-frame-from-spring-boot/) how to load the context successfully. However, what about integration tests?

### MyApplicationTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

@Test
public void contextLoads() {
}
}
```

### MyApplication.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder
            (DesktopAppConfig.class)
            .headless(false).run(args)) {
    }
```

### DesktopAppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DesktopAppConfig {

@Bean
public Object someBean() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message");
    return new Object();
    }
}
```

This simple integration test will throw a java.awt.HeadlessException, and I couldn't find in the Spring Boot reference any way of setting the context to headless through the integration test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customise the `SpringApplication` that's used by your integration tests via a custom `SpringApplicationContextLoader`. Instead of using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` which configures the use of the default `SpringApplicationContextLoader`, you should use `@ContextConfiguration` and the `loader` attribute to configure a custom context loader:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class, loader=CustomSpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

In your `CustomSpringApplicationContextLoader` implementation, override `getSpringApplication()` and set `headless` to `false`:

```
public class CustomSpringApplicationContextLoader extends SpringApplicationContextLoader {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplication getSpringApplication() {
        return new SpringApplicationBuilder().headless(false).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like `SpringApplicationContextLoader` is now deprecated and `SpringBootContextLoader` should be used instead.